# Android Calendar Provider - Create calendar prompt with specific calendar ID using intent

Tags: java, android, events, android-intent, calendar

Using a calendar intent, is it possible for me to specify a calendar ID? Rather than the current method of it opening up the last used calendar.

In this scenario, I want to use the calendar intent, not using the contentresolver.

I've tried using

```
.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
```

But that did not work with cal ID 6 (which does exist in my phone)

```
private void createEventPrompt(String title, String location, String description, long startTimeMillis, long endTimeMillis) {
    //Create event with prompts, see the following for the extra options:
    //http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents

    //Android Bug in 5.0.1 - Does not let you specify an end time

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTimeMillis)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTimeMillis)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
    startActivity(intent);

    //Last method called in application, so close loading dialog
    exitEventAddingActivity();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: Open the calendar intent with filled in data in a specific calendar. Currently it opens the calendar intent with the last used calendar

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to find a solution and left it as is. If you do find out, please post

Comment: is it possible with contentResolver?

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. It's been more than a year. Any luck yet?